# how to Add to favorites in android recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, boolean-logic

I have an android recyclerview,
i load and display images on it.

I am successful with that now i want to add some images to favorites, based on clicking on corresponding icons.

How do i do it?

any help would be useful.
I have a model class and adapter as well

Comment: create a array list for fav and store all the postion or id of the images and store this and set a if check on binding if its equal to your fav list its show

Comment: Please help us to help you :-) Add some source code to see what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model class add a field for favourites with data type as int. The reason for int as a data type is because it's mutable i.e, it can be changed.
Lets assume

```
int favourite
```

In your recycler view add a checkbox, and attach a condition saying if it is checked `int favourite = 1` i.e, it is favourite and if it is unchecked `int favourite = 0` and save the information in your database.